# Can I var scope a function? Prevent it from appearing in the global variables scope

Tags: function, coldfusion, scope

I'm cleaning up a large website's huge variables scope, normally when cleaning up these things I find the variables and var scope them.

Problem is; say I have a function declaration in a view(cfscript):

```
function myFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
```

myFunction is now available in the variables scope, it is however only used on this page so i want it in the local scope.

I've tried:

```
function local.myFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
//error!

var myFunction = "";
function myFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
//just creates a local string and a global function...

var function myFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
//no error but function is still not local...
```

the following however does work, it does feel kinda nasty though...

```
function myTMPFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
var myFunction = myTMPFunction;
structDelete(VARIABLES, "myTMPFunction");
```

is there no better, clean way?

Comment: In the next release on ColdFusion there will be "closures" which I believe will allow you to do what you want, using `var myFunction = closure(){ ... }` or `local.myFunction = closure(){ ... }` (although we've yet to see exactly how things will be implemented).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment to Sergii's post,

> its used recursive to generate HTML

I would say maybe you should refactor the function into a custom tag.

I generally avoid directly outputting anything from functions and use Custom Tags instead. When I use functions I *return* some value (or void).

Without more specific information on what the function does, though, it will be hard to give a more concrete answer than that.

However, while not the prettiest, I think your work-around solution would also work, if you'd rather not go through the effort to use a Custom Tag.

```
function myTMPFunction(){
    //doStuff
}
var myFunction = myTMPFunction;
structDelete(VARIABLES, "myTMPFunction");
```

Comment: well its actually the scope of the CFC that called the page(in this case the coldbox renderer). the variables scope lasts as long as the CFC does , meaning, until a framework reinit. with slow requests some of the variables of one request get mixed up with another's request tending to give strange and wrong results.

Answer (score 2):

> is there no better, clean way?

Yes, there is. It is called [ColdFusion components](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7fec.html) aka CFC.

I suspect that you mis-use local scope concept a bit, but you did not say whether your code is inside a CFC or not, so I can only guess: if you are refactoring CFC, what you want is incapsulation, otherwise you just want to start using components and *then* local scope inside the methods.

Comment: I know about CFC's, since the site uses coldbox i use them quite a lot, however lets pretend it is used on exactly one page and it needs to be a function because its used recursive to generate HTML. I wouldn't normally create a CFC for something like that.

Comment: OK, this makes sense. Sorry for misunderstanding, your reasons sound not clear. I guess you cannot really "hide" functions from variables scope, possibly just organize by aliasing in other scope. For example `function foo() {}; request.functions.foo = foo;`.

Answer (score 0):

The local scope is only really important within the context of a function.  The reason that you var scope variables in a cfc is so that variables that should be local to a function don't leak out of the scope of the function into the component.  This becomes especially important if you have components in a persistent scope like session or application.

```
component{

    public void function leakyVariable(){
            //this is in variables scope so a) it will exist longer 

            //than this function call and other functions can access it
        foo = "Foo"; 

        //do stuff
    }

    public void function grabLeakyVariable(){
            //look i have a foo
        var foobar = foo & "bar";
    }

}
```